# manintain a schema.rb in a rails engine and run migrations that update in the engine's schema.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-activerecord, rails-engines

I have a rails engine that currently has a migration file

my_engine/db/migrate/20190611032851_add_columns_to_products.rb

```
class AddColumnsToInsuranceProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :insurance_products, :description_ms, :string
  end
end
```

I know that to keep my engine's migrations separate from my main application and to get it to run when i run rake db:migrate from my application, tutorials say i should do this

```
   initializer :append_migrations do |app|
      unless app.root.to_s.match root.to_s
        config.paths["db/migrate"].expanded.each do |expanded_path|
          app.config.paths["db/migrate"] << expanded_path
        end
      end
    end
```

At the moment, i have two databases and i want to be able to create a schema.rb file in my engine as my_engine/db/schema.rb and be able to run `rake db:migrate` and it updates only my rails_engine's table an schema.rb.

What would be the easiest and seamless way to do this?

Comment: I'm confused by your question. A schema defines the full structure of a database. A rails engine is "attached" to a database; it does not define the full database itself - so it wouldn't make sense for an engine to have a `schema.rb` file.

Comment: For example, look at `devise` -- it has a test suite with a dummy rails application, which contains a "minimal" database: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/test/rails_app/db/schema.rb -- however, the library itself does not contain a `db/schema.rb` file.